# Signing up during answer post can cause (partial) loss of answer

Tags: bug, login, new-users, sign-up

I just typed out an answer to a site on the SE network I did not use before ([linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/36873/30314)).

After completing, I clicked on 'sign in' > 'sign in with google' to leverage my network account that has google login capability.

As soon as I finished the login+account creation, I was shown my post, and to my horror only the first 2 lines remained (out of 15 or so). In a moment of clarity I went back 5x to the previous page and found my full text but otherwise this would have been a pretty sad entry to the new site.

I am using an up to date version of chrome on a mac, but (though I don't sign up for a new site every day) I think I had this at least once before, perhaps a year ago. So suspect there is either a missing autosave when clicking the button that leaves the page, or an issue that not necessarily the latest version is displayed.

Comment: After being pointed in the right direction I closed this as a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330607/answer-draft-is-lost-if-you-click-to-sign-up